# gzipping of components not working according to yslow

Tags: c#, web-config, gzip, yslow

I have the following setup in my web.config (within system.webSever tag) to compress components such as javascript and css with gzip. However it does not seem to be working as when I run YSlow against my site I still get the recommendation to gzip the components.

```
<httpCompression minFileSizeForComp="0" doDiskSpaceLimiting="false"
          staticCompressionDisableCpuUsage="98" staticCompressionEnableCpuUsage="95"
          dynamicCompressionEnableCpuUsage="30" dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage="60"
          directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
        <staticTypes>
            <clear />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true" />
        </staticTypes>
        <dynamicTypes>
            <clear />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true" />
        </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

I am running the site in IIS7 in classic mode, which I think may be my problem. Does the site need to be integrated mode in IIS7 for this to fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following node on the same level as the httpCompression element:

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/urlCompression